# Codeigniter Cron job which consume more time then insert to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a `cron job` which call the following `codeigniter controller`
But it is ***time costly***
Which calculate and operate more operations (on average need 5 minutes)
Then insert values on database

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mycron extends CI_Controller {

    public function cron_function()
    {
        // simulate time cost operations
        sleep(300); // 5 mint = 5 *60 = 300 sec

        $this->load->database();    // line1
        $this->db->reconnect();     // line2

        $this           -> db -> set    ( 'source_id',  '11');
        $this           -> db -> set    ( 'title',  'TTL');
        $query = $this  -> db -> insert ( 'my_table' );

        echo 'END ...'; 
    }
}
```

My issue
Without both lines line1/line2
When database try to connect after consumed time on operationsthe result will be

```
SQL Error: 2006: MySQL server has gone away
```

Then when try to apply the fix RE_CONNECT to database by using 2 lines
We face

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at .../system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:392)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 568
Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on boolean
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 392
Backtrace:
```

Comment: check the `wait_timeout` variable in your `my.cnf'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a second method in cron controller responsible only for inserting data into database.

Then, after time costly operation is finished, you could post the generated data with, say, [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) to the second method, thus going around MySQL timeout limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled auto-loading of `database` library
Old code

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

to be

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

And load it manually before calling DB statement

```
$this->load->database();
```

So the database connection will open after time of costly operation will be finished

Then this time (of costly operation) will NOT considered as a database *synchronous operation time*
Opposite of auto-loading of `database` library which start timer when page loaded

Comment: also remove `$this->db->reconnect();` statement

Answer (score 0):

You must use **insert_batch()** which is way to faster than insert().

Check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#inserting-data for detailed info.